# Conditions to unlock Alchemist Discoveries when playing another class

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Again, another question about Pathfinder.

This time it's about classes that can get Alchemist's [Discoveries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries)
 without actual Alchemist levels. The Rogue is a good example with his [Bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-su) Rogue Talent to use Alchemist's Bombs and get [Bomber's Discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-s-discovery-su) to improve them.

Most of the time, when getting Discoveries from other classes than Alchemist, you have a text like

> Treat your [insert class here] level as Alchemist level for determining the effects of discoveries and whether you are able to select one.

But absolutely nothing is mentioned about equivalent class levels in the case of Bomber's Discovery. Then : Can a Rogue take a Discovery that normally requires an Alchemist level with his Bomber's Discovery Talent, although nothing is clearly mentioned ?

Comment: Well, I would really like the Breath Weapon Bomb for example. It sounds funny, and practical in some situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A creature must meet prerequisites unless the creature's specifically told it needn't meet prerequisites

*Pathfinder* has been pretty clear throughout that a thing's prerequisites must be met before a thing can be taken. In this case, it's the rogue talents [bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-su) and, subsequently, [bomber's discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-s-discovery-su). The latter doesn't say it eliminates the need for the creature to meet the prerequisites of the [alchemist's discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries), so, sadly, the rogue must meet the discovery's prerequisites. This vastly limits the rogue's choices, putting out of reach for the typical single-classed rogue, for example, the alchemist discovery [breath weapon bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/breath-weapon-bomb), which has as a prerequisite being a level 6 alchemist.

### A possible house rule

In a high-level campaign featuring an increasingly marginalized rogue, this DM would consider a homebrew master talent like [bomber's discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-s-discovery-su) that *either* waives one or more [alchemist's discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries) prerequisites *or* grants the rogue an effective alchemist level equal to his rogue level for the purposes of meeting an alchemist's discovery's prerequisites.